# Conecting to MySQL with PHP session

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone explain to me what the following lines of code mean together?

```
if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
```

I know what these functions mean separately but in what situations can you use it?

**session_satus()** is to check if a session is already started and active.

**session_start()** is used to create a session or resume the current one.

Is it okay to establish it before connecting to the database?

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

Comment: Those functions together mean `If there is no session: create a new session`.

The session and DB connections are completely unrelated, although you're probably better starting the session right at the start of your script

Answer (score 0):

**Recommended way for versions of PHP >= 5.4.0**

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
```

**For versions of PHP < 5.4.0**

> For [session_start();](https://php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php) is used to return the current session status.

```
if(session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the correct version of your code should be :

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
```